# How to reduce space between label and a text box in html

Tags: html, css

I am designing a html form where I have a label and a textbox, but in my design there is a big space between the textbox and the label, which I want to reduce.

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <bean:message key="tml.registration.captcha.verification.code"/>
    <font color='red'>*</font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="imageValidation" size="25" title="Enter verification Code"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <logic:messagesPresent property="imageValidation">
      <font color="red"><html:errors property="imageValidation" /></font>
    </logic:messagesPresent>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I want the verification code and textbox closely aligned. Somebody please help.
Here is a screenshot of the current state:

[image]

Comment: Given my answer. check it out.

Comment: it depends on your table and td's width, you can smallize your td's or merge them and insert all of your contols inside it,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign small width for the `td` and apply `nowrap` style. Update your code like below.

```
<tr>
  <td width="3" nowrap>
    <bean:message key="tml.registration.captcha.verification.code" />
    <font color='red'>*      </font>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="imageValidation" size="25" title="Enter verification Code" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <logic:messagesPresent property="imageValidation"> 
      <font color="red"><html:errors property="imageValidation" /></font>
    </logic:messagesPresent>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**

If this `table-row` comes up with so many other content, then create one `table` inside the `td` like below.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="3" nowrap>
          <bean:message key="tml.registration.captcha.verification.code" />
          <font color='red'>*</font>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="text" name="imageValidation" size="25" title="Enter verification Code" />
       </td>
       <td>
         <logic:messagesPresent property="imageValidation"> 
          <font color="red"><html:errors property="imageValidation" /></font>
         </logic:messagesPresent>
       </td>
      </tr>
    </table>       
 </tr>
```